# Use ConvXDtranspose on Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I wanted to use the layer Conv2Dtranspose and Conv3Dtranspose of Keras in order to do deconvolution (upsampling and convolution at the same time). I can get my model built and compiled, but the upsampling part does not seem to work, even when I modify the parameter `dilate_rate`.

Any idea how to do the upsampling part using ConvXDtranspose?

Or am I misunderstanding how this layer works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how this works. The `dilate_rate` parameter is about the convolution radius to allow "a trou" convolutions.